# groovy syntax for executing unix command with process output

Tags: shell, groovy

I'm trying to execute a shell command in groovy. The command is `diff <(ls dir1) <(ls dir2)`. From the shell, that works fine, but when I do `"diff <(ls dir1) <(ls dir2)".execute()` in groovy, I get a shell error saying `diff: extra operand`. I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax for this in groovy. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can live with calling this via `bash` like you do on command line, then the syntax to call by shell is:

```
def p = ["/bin/bash", "-c", "diff <(ls dir1) <(ls dir2)"].execute()
p.waitFor()
println p.text
```

The reason you can not simply run above code: `execute()` does just a simple process execution.  So you can only run commands and pass param.  So e.g. `'diff file1 file1'.execute()` will work.  But the `<(...)` is bash-speak for "create me a named pipe".  But you can pass to any(?) shell a "command" with `-c` param to execute it, so you can utilize the power of the shell.  Calling it as an array of strings in my example saves you the hastle with quoting/escaping everything properly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that workaround. But I'm really trying to figure out WHY it doesn't work how I tried it.

Comment: @JeffStorey i have added some explanation.  Basically it is like `|` or other "shellisms".  The regular unix execute can not understand this -- only `cmd param1 ... paramN`