# Jenkins groovy script execution for dynamic parameters

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to use active choice parameters in jenkins . I am executing a shell command and trying to show the output in the choice parameters.
1) Working scenario -

Text file already generated by the output of shell command and able to see the parameters -

```
list = []
def process = "cat /home/ansible/test1.txt".execute()
process.text.eachLine {list.add it}
return list
```

Here test1.txt is already populated with the values

2) Failure scenario 
Instead of pre-populating the file trying the get the shell command output and write into a file and then show it to the choice parameters-

```
list = []
def process1=" sh script.sh > test1.txt".execute()
def process = "cat /home/ansible/test1.txt".execute()
process.text.eachLine {list.add it}
return list
```

This is not working

Is there any suggestions ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [groovy syntax for executing unix command with process output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277377/groovy-syntax-for-executing-unix-command-with-process-output)

Comment: Also jenkins has it's own `sh` command to work around that

Answer (score 1):

Use pure groovy to read file lines

```
new File('/home/ansible/test1.txt').readLines()
```

---

For your case - wrap your code with try-catch to see the error.

Without error message it's hard to help you...

```
try{
  def list ....
}catch(e){ return [e.toString()] }
```

Comment: Thanks . But in Jenkins , where should I get the groovy script related errors.

Comment: you should see the output in the Jenkins server log.

Comment: With try-catch you should see error directly in drop-down. BTW, the other problem in your code - you are not waiting till the end of the process.

Comment: Thanks , I solved it . It seems I was using some environment variable which wasn't getting evaluated , could you pls elaborate "not waiting till the end of the process" ?

Comment: for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44372447/curl-request-from-command-line-and-via-groovy-script/44383995#44383995